# How to add a SVG inside circle?

Tags: svg

I have a svg and I need to insert it inside a circle. is a way to do this?

I am creating the circle like

```
const circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
  circle.setAttribute('pointer-events', 'visiblePoint');
  circle.setAttribute('cx', (pointPosition1.x).toString());
  circle.setAttribute('cy', (pointPosition1.y).toString());
  circle.setAttribute('r', '10');
  circle.setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
```

Best,
Hmendezm

Comment: Use the circle as a clipPath to clip the SVG.

Comment: Thx Robert. I have never used clipPath. Let me check it.